# OAuth2 Dialog (popup) permission removed from Google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dialog, web, google-signin

Did the OAuth2 Dialog box get removed from Google Sign-In for Web sites?

Previously, when our users were connecting to our website it was displaying a popup window (OAuth2 Dialog) asking our user if they wanted to give their permission in order to share their basic info.

Today this popup window is not showing up anymore and our user is directly connected to the website.

I did some testing. Etsy has the same "issue" as us - no OAuth2 Dialog, only the account selection is required. But for DropBox, the OAuth2 Dialog is showing because they ask to be able to "Manage your contacts".

Is it because we are just asking for the basic info and not deep permission that Goggle is not displaying the OAuth2 Dialog window?

Or Google did some update of the OAuth` Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth popup window shows up and first checks if there is an active session of Google, if yes it will immediately close and redirect you to your app as you have an active session of google and no need to login again.